# How to pass custom data in jeditable

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I have field being updated by jeditable
It is a file name so I show file name like "filename...." if it is long.

i want to use of data  $(this).data("id") but it show undefined

if console it in submit data it show correct value.

Here is my code.

```
<span id="2012_03_10 15_05_46.jpg" class="rename" title="Doubleclick to edit...">2012_03_10 15_...</span>
<span id="2012_03_10 15_05_47.jpg" class="rename" title="Doubleclick to edit...">2012_03_10 15_...</span>
<span id="2012_03_10 15_05_48.jpg" class="rename" title="Doubleclick to edit...">2012_03_10 15_...</span>

$(".rename").editable("process.php", { 
    data : $(this).data("id"),
    //placeholder : "txt -  "+$(this).attr('id'),
    indicator : "<img src='images/indicator.gif'>",
    tooltip   : "Doubleclick to edit...",
    event     : "dblclick",
    onblur    : "submit",
    style     : "inherit",
    submitdata : function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("id"));
        return {action : 'rename_file'};
    }
});
```

how can I access that correct value as data.
and also separate value for each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This working fine

```
<span id="folder.jpg" class="rename" data-attribute="folder.jpg" title="Doubleclick to edit...">folder.jpg</span>

$(".rename").editable("process.php", { 
data : $(this).data("attribute"),
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).data("id")` only works if your are using  any `event` like `click`, if not then you have to use your `selector` for this like,

```
$(".rename").editable("process.php", { 
    data : $(".rename").data("id"), // use .rename instead of this
    // your remaining code
```

Yes, `$(this)` will work fine in `submitData`

If you have only `id` then try this `data : $(".rename").attr("id")`, but according to your `edited question` you have to use `looping` for `unique every rename span` like

**HTML**

```
<span data-id="2012_03_10 15_05_48.jpg" class="rename" title="Doubleclick to edit...">2012_03_10 15_...</span>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(".rename").each(function(){
    $(this).editable("process.php", { 
       data : $(this).data("id"),
       // your code;
    });// end of editable code
});// end of each loop
```

Comment: You have `data-attribute` on `rename class element` ?

Comment: No data-attribute not used.
may be that will be used a lot.